# Socket server no longer works when a client leaves

Tags: python, sockets

My program works fine until a client leaves. After the client leaves, I am getting an error which is on the host server,

**Following is the code I am trying:**

```
import socket
import threading

class ChatServer:

    clients_list = []

    last_received_message = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.server_socket = None
        self.create_listening_server()

    def create_listening_server(self):
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        local_ip = '127.0.0.1'
        local_port = 10319
        # this will allow you to immediately restart a TCP server
        self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        # this makes the server listen to requests coming from other computers on the network
        self.server_socket.bind((local_ip, local_port))
        print("Listening for incoming messages..")
        self.server_socket.listen(5)
        self.receive_messages_in_a_new_thread()

    def receive_messages(self, so):
        while True:
            incoming_buffer = so.recv(256)
            if not incoming_buffer:
                break
            self.last_received_message = incoming_buffer.decode('utf-8')
            self.broadcast_to_all_clients(so)  # send to all clients
        so.close()

    def broadcast_to_all_clients(self, senders_socket):
        for client in self.clients_list:
            socket, (ip, port) = client
            if socket is not senders_socket:
                socket.sendall(self.last_received_message.encode('utf-8'))

    def receive_messages_in_a_new_thread(self):
        while True:
            client = so, (ip, port) = self.server_socket.accept()
            self.add_to_clients_list(client)
            print('Connected to ', ip, ':', str(port))
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_messages, args=(so,))
            t.start()

    def add_to_clients_list(self, client):
        if client not in self.clients_list:
            self.clients_list.append(client)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ChatServer()
```

The error (ConnectionResetError) is at `incoming_buffer = so.recv(256)`.

Does anyone know what is the wrong with above code?

Comment: What does the rest of the error say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code.  You just need to use `try`/`except` to catch this error and break out of the loop.

Python has a `socketserver` module built-in that handles much of this overhead.

Comment: `while True:` / `.try:` / `..incoming_buffer = so.recv(256)` / `.except NetworkError:` / `..break` / `.if not incoming_buffer:` / `..break`.  Dots show the indentation level.  You need to substitute whatever exception you're really getting.

Comment: Okay, so I used that and when someone leaves, at "socket.sendall(self.last_received_message.encode('utf-8'))", I get an OSError ([Errno 9] Bad file descriptor). Help.

Comment: When someone leaves, you have to remove them from the socket list.  Are you doing that?

Comment: I have a socket list, but I don't know how to get the ip of the person that leaves.

Comment: In that "except NetworkError" clause, you have the `so` of the socket that failed.  Can you look it up by that?

Comment: I don’t really understand how to do that. I don’t really know a lot about sockets. I followed a tutorial and changed a few things, so I don’t really know a lot about that. If you could explain how to do that, it would be great.

Comment: It isn't really related to sockets.  The broadcaster sends to everything in self.client_list.  When the socket closes, just remove that entry from self.client_list.   Scan through the list looking for the entry where the first item is the closed socket, then remove that entry.

Comment: That wasn’t very clear. Are you saying that the first entry of the list is the closed socket?

Comment: Have you looked at the code?  What it's adding to the `client_list` is `socket, (ip, port)`.  So, if you want to remove an entry, and you have the `socket`, then you need to find the entry where your socket matches the first element if the list item.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks!